# How to install Kudu?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-kudu

I am familiar with hadoop components like hive, hbase, hdfs etc. But i am very new to Apache Kudu.

So far, from my research i understood that kudu is nothing but columnar storage like parquet. Also it's faster as Hbase.

But i am still unable to find any efficient document for kudu installation. Even i am wondering whether i really need to install any seperate package for kudu or its inbuild in hadoop(EMR or Dataproc).

Please help how can i start hands-on on kudu.

Comment: A very bad take on the matter. For example, it is mutable.

Answer (score 3):

Kudu is NOT a file format but rather a different storage engine. Consider it to be a parallel/alternative file system to your HDFS (or S3). Yes, it DOES require installation of Master and Tablet servers, see [Architecture Overview](https://kudu.apache.org/docs/#_architectural_overview) on Apache web site.

And since its an open source Apache project, installation instructions can also be found on Apache web site: https://kudu.apache.org/docs/installation.html.

Comment: @thebluephantom  In terms of being too coarse-grained, all-or-nothing? Yeah, tru dat... Hopefully it'll get better with Ranger integration https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.1.1/administering-kudu/topics/kudu-enabling-ranger-authorization.html

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha for your answer. Can i install kudu on newly created EC2 machine where hadoop doesn't exist?  or i need to install kudu on top of hadoop ?

Comment: By itself, Kudu doesn't depend on any part of Hadoop ecosystem. Although Spark, Impala and Hive Metastore can be tools to process data stored in Kudu.